# Oracle - Search for text - Retrieve snippet of result

Tags: regex, node.js, oracle, search

I'm currently building a simple search page in Node JS Express and Oracle.

I'd like to show the user a snippet of the matching text (first instance would do) to add a *bit* context of what the SQL found.

Example:

Search term: *'fish'*

Results: *Henry really likes going **fish**ing, and once he caug ...*

I'm not sure the best way to approach this - I could retrieve the whole block of text and do it in Node JS, but I don't really like the idea of dragging the whole text across to the app, just to get a snippet.

I've been thinking that `REGEXP_SUBSTR` could be way to do it... But I'm not sure whether I could use a regular expression to retrieve `x` amount of characters before and after the matching word.

Have I got the right idea or am I going about it in the wrong way?

Thanks

```
SELECT text
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(text), LOWER('fish')) AS potential_snippet
  FROM table
 WHERE LOWER(text) LIKE LOWER('%fish%');
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use oracle text for text searching purpose? It have markup of search text too. In your example you'll just get keyword as potential_snippet where it exist and nulls where it isn't.

Comment: Thanks Nagh. I've considered using Oracle text - but the fact that the indexes need to be rebuilt on every `INSERT` concerns me. I've been playing around with a` CONTEXT` index, and the execution time is 6+ seconds on a `CONTAINS` search, compared to just over 1 second searching for the same thing using `LIKE` (for the same search term).

Comment: I'm also not sure what the REGEX pattern would be - i'm trying `/fish(?<=fish)(?!.*fish).{15}/` but it's not quite right, and also (as you say) returns NULL - this is why I'm uncertain if REGEX_SUSBTR is a good way to do this (and whether I just not know how to us it, or if I am completely wrong with my approach!)

Comment: If you need a JS regex for extracting some context around a keyword, you can try [`/\b.{0,15}fish.{0,15}\b/i`](https://regex101.com/r/uN7tN5/1)

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape Its not a big deal to rebuild index, however it does cost some processing power and time. So there will be some delay, before newly added rows will be available for the search. So, if you won't use oracle text, in my practice its much more efficient to implement markup feature ouside the query. JS can do a highligting job better :)

Comment: @doublesidestickytape And for regexp, this site might help https://regex101.com/

Comment: Hah - indeed! Perhaps a CONTEXT index is the right way to go - but users can add a bunch of stuff in real-time. I thought about having a trigger on insert to rebuild, but it doesn't feel right. I want people to be able to search for content as it comes in - so even if I rebuilt the index every 'x' hours - it could cause issues. That said - I don't claim to be an expert and will heed your advice if you think it is a fundamental mistake to use LIKE! My biggest concern with highlighting is dragging over a 3K char text, just to grab a snippet - which is why (I think) - doing on the DB is better

Comment: And naturally, letting the view handle the any keyword matches (putting them in bold) or whatever.

Comment: @doublesidedstickytape You don't have to wait hours to run index update, you can do it immediatly, however it might take some time. I understand your concern. If you prefer not to use oracle text, then use solution based on Christian_I answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nagh - I've done as you've suggested with a CONTEXT index, and I've set it to sync every minute. I've set a scheduler job to rebuild the index monthly to keep it optimised. It's very quick! Thank you for all your help :D

Comment: @Nagh no problem, however I'd recommed you to improve this solution. if it is possible, launch rebuild of index only when changes made (and create a smart queue, through scheduler for example to avoid concurrent sync jobs), and may be run it every N-hours to be sure that all is in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select text
     , SUBSTR( TEXT, INSTR(LOWER(TEXT),'fish', 1)-50,100 )
  FROM test
 WHERE INSTR(LOWER(text),'fish', 1)<>0;
```

Play with the position and length numbers(50 and 100 in my example) to limit the length of the string.

Comment: Thank you Cristian_I - that almost works for me - need to play around with the position and length as you say, as anything starting with 'fish' doesn't get picked up - perhaps a `CASE` statement could resolve this?

Comment: I think this has sorted it - 

`SUBSTR(LOWER(text), CASE WHEN INSTR(LOWER(text), '%fish%', 1) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE -50 END, 100) AS snippet`

Comment: I've edited the code. I think this is a more elegant approach than using 'CASE'

Answer (score 1):

If you need to extract some context with the help of JavaScript, you can use limiting quantifiers in a regex:

```
/\b.{0,15}fish.{0,15}\b/i
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN7tN5/1)

Here,

- `\b` - matches at the word boundary (so that the context contains only whole words)
- `.{0,15}` - any characters other than a newline (replace with `[\s\S]` or `[^]` if you need to include newlines)
- `fish` - the keyword

The `/i` modifier enables case-insensitive search.

If you need a dynamic regex creation, use a constructor notation:

```
RegExp("\\b.{0,15}" + keyword + ".{0,15}\\b", "i");
```

Also, if you need to find multiple matches, use `g` modifier alongside the `i`.

Comment: Thank you stribizhev for your answer - very thorough and clear. I'm still unsure whether to tackle this SQL-side, or not yet - this is certainly a solution though, Thank you again.

Comment: Please take your time and only accept the solution that works for you best.